# ExecuteNonQuery() Syntax Error c#

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

Ok, so I've seen this question in many **MANY** other threads, but never get a complete answer (at least so far).
So I have a basic code to insert a new user with all of it's info into a MySQL database (localhost), and I have basically done the same code a previous time, and it worked.
It isn't the length of the sentence, since the column can handle at least 40 chars.

The error:

```
 MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Clave='9cdfb439c7876e703e307864c9167a15'' at line 1'
```

My code:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var nomCom = Nombre.Text + Apellido.Text;            

        /*var exists = Query.Check($"SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM usuario WHERE Nombre_Usu='{NombreUsu.Text}'");

        if (!exists)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nombre de usuario ya existe","VERIFIQUE",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
        }
        else
        {*/
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nomCom) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NombreUsu.Text) || txtContra.Password.ToString() != txtConfirmar.Password.ToString())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Verifique los campos porfavor :)", "ERROR", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return;
            }

            Query.Execute($"INSERT usuario SET Nombre='{Nombre.Text}', Apellido='{Apellido.Text}', Nombre_Usu='{NombreUsu.Text}' Clave='{txtContra.Password.Encriptar()}'");
       // }

    }
```

Alright, that is the code for the Register form/window, where the user will input the data and insert that into the DB. The "Query.Check" is another class (Query) in which I wrote the SQL methods, to reuse code and save space.
Oh and the ".Encriptar()" is just a method to hash the password. 
Here it is:

```
     public static long Execute(string query)
    {
        var con = Connection.Create();
        var command = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return command.LastInsertedId;
    }
```

So... I don't know why this isn't working, since I did exactly the same thing with a previous app and worked just fine!
Please, someone help me.
Btw, I'm new here, so sorry if I didn't write the post correctly.

Comment: The *first* thing to do is to stop building SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL, every time.

Comment: You have wrong syntax used for `INSERT` statement. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-insert-query.htm or https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-insert-query.htm

Comment: Did you try reading the error and looking at your query string?

Comment: 1) You are missing a comma, 2) you are mixing up INSERT and UPDATE and 3) you are opening up your database to SQL injection. No wonder you didn't find one single answer solving all your problems...

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a , in your sql

```
, Nombre_Usu='{NombreUsu.Text}' Clave='{txtContra.Password.Encriptar()}'
```

needs to be

```
, Nombre_Usu='{NombreUsu.Text}', Clave='{txtContra.Password.Encriptar()}'
```

Beyond that, use paramatized queries ( lots of questions on here about that )

Comment: Yup, that was it, can't believe I let that pass. Thanks dude, saved my mind and team. And thanks Jon Skeet and CodeCaster, will definitely implement parameterized SQL. But about the INSERT syntax, actually works with the SET statement, feel like it saves some lines but yeah, will improve. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL syntax for the INSERT is incorrect.  It should be

```
INSERT INTO usuario (Nombre, Apellido, Nombre_Usu, Clave) VALUES (@Nombre, @Apellido, @Nombre_Usu, @Clave)
```

Also as Jon stated in the comments, you will want to parameterize your query.